# how i fix [java.lang.NullPointerException]?

Tags: android

I have problem in `Myfragment.java`. this line is problem part. have null

```
binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
```

**Myfragment.java**

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ScheduleListAdapter adapter = new ScheduleListAdapter();
    binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
    binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my,container,false);

    MyViewModel homeViewModel =
            new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
    goroutinesetbtn =  view.findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
    binding = FragmentMyBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();
    MyViewModel.getSchedule().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),schedules ->{
        adapter.setScheduleList(schedules);
            }
    );
    goroutinesetbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RoutineSettingActivity.class); //fragment라서 activity intent와는 다른 방식
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

**ScheduleListAdapter.java**

```
public ScheduleListAdapter(){
    list = new ArrayList<>();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ScheduleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_schedule,parent,false);
    return new ScheduleViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ScheduleViewHolder holder, int position) {
 holder.setSchedule(list.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

void setScheduleList(ArrayList<Schedule> list){
    this.list = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class ScheduleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
 ListScheduleBinding listScheduleBinding;
    public ScheduleViewHolder(@NonNull View scheduleView) {
        super(scheduleView);
        listScheduleBinding=ListScheduleBinding.bind(scheduleView);
    }
    public void setSchedule(Schedule schedule){
        listScheduleBinding.tvtitle.setText(schedule.getTitle());
        listScheduleBinding.tvcolor.setText(schedule.getColor());
        listScheduleBinding.tvstart.setText(schedule.getStart());
        listScheduleBinding.tvend.setText(schedule.getLast());
    }
}
```

**Schedule.java**

```
public Schedule(){}

public String getStart() {
    return start;
}

public String getLast() {
    return last;
}

public String getColor() {return color;}

public String getTitle() {return title;}

public void setStart(String start) {
    this.start = start;
}

public void setLast(String last) {
    this.last = last;
}

public void setColor(String color) {this.color = color;}

public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}


public Schedule(String title, String start, String last, String color){
    this.title = title;
    this.start = start;
    this.last = last;
    this.color = color;
}
```

Comment: Try initializing binding before accessing the RecyclerView by moving the line binding = FragmentMyBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false); above the line that sets the LayoutManager and adapter.